# Laravel / axios not returning response json only status code error

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, axios

I am throwing an exception and handling it in handler.php, but it doesn't return the message:
My handler looks like this:

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if($exception instanceof ModelNotFoundException){
        return response()->json([ 'message' => ''.str_replace('App\\', '', $exception->getModel()).' not found.'], 404);
    }

    if($exception instanceof AuthenticationException){
        return response()->json(['message' => "Unauthorized1"], 401);
    }

    if($exception instanceof InvalidStateException){
        return response()->json(['message' => $exception->getMessage()], 400);
    }
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

But changes reflect only if I change the status code not the message. At my frontend I am using axios and when I catch the exception there is no json in it. This is how my message looks in chrome:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login 401 (Unauthorized)
remote.js:11 Error: Request failed with status code 401
    at e.exports (spread.js:25)
    at e.exports (spread.js:25)
    at XMLHttpRequest.d.onreadystatechange (spread.js:25)
```

This is my axios request:

```
const login = (user) => axios.post(base + 'api/login', user).catch(e => console.log(e));
```

Answer (score 0):

It was actually from the axios request I should do it like

```
catch(e => console.log(e.response));
```